# Http status 404 not found error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I used eclipse and tomcat and created a dynamic web project following this tutorial:

https://o7planning.org/en/10169/java-servlet-tutorial

I followed all the steps until running the code for the first time to display 'Hello, World!' on a webpage, but it gave the following error. I have added index.html properly.

What could be the issue? Yesterday I created another dynamic project in the same workspace that the simple project was run it, but it's not working either. Could it be a port issue?

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message /ServletFirstTutorial/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.14

```
web.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <display-name>ServletFirstTutorial</display-name>





   <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

Comment: did it display at first Time?

Comment: "I followed all the steps ... I have added index.html properly". Chances are, you made a mistake while following the steps, but without seeing any code/configuration, we'll be none the wiser.

Comment: 404 simply means the path you are trying to access was not mapped to the servlet path. Can you please post your URL and the servlet mapping?

Comment: @SudipBolakhe cant we run jsp page ?

Comment: @Stultuske see that tutorial link, while first time running it has added only index.html and then browser screen is displaying there. it should give output right?

Comment: @Stultuske see the web.xml file

Comment: *We* can't see that you've "added index.html properly". How did you?